# Correct Process for Editing an Admin Order

Tags: orders, administration

This one confuses me quite alot and I'm wondering if someone can outline the correct process to edit an order.
My Confusion:

1. I open the order and click Edit
2. I complete the order form and create the product (New ID appended with -1 & Status Pending)
3. I open the -1 order and invoice which sets it to processing.
4. Now I am unsure what to do with the original order, it gives you the options to Edit, Credit Memo, Hold and Ship.

What should I do with the original Order?

Hope someone can explain it to me.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Did you manage to find a fitting method?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sander, I would personally take your approach as well. Hopefully over time others will post here to give alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on how your bookkeeping is set up, although I don't run a Magento shop myself most of my clients create a credit memo / cancel for the original order and only book the newly created, edited, invoice. And also ship that one.

But again, this is purely from a administrative point of view. There's no 'best practice' that is better from a Magento standpoint.